# Error while extracting text from Images using Tesseract with Java

Tags: java, tesseract

[image]

**

- Code:

**

```
> import net.sourceforge.tess4j.*;
> 
> import java.io.File;
> 
> public class imageTest {
> 
>     public static void main(String[] args) {
> 
>         Tesseract tesseract = new Tesseract();
>         try {
>             tesseract.setDatapath("tessdata/");
>             String text = tesseract.doOCR(new File("images/01_image.png"));
>             System.out.print(text);
>         }
> 
>         catch (TesseractException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         }
>     } }
```

**

- Error

**:
read_params_file: parameter not found: enable_new_segsearch

Answer (score 0):

Check out https://github.com/tesseract-ocr/tesseract/issues/1620
As a summary they say that it occurs when you use a new version of Tesseract with an old version of trained data. Check if two versions are the same